# twitter json - unable to convert to jobject or jarray using json.net / javascriptserializer

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net, javascriptserializer

I am been stuck on this for 3 days now...I have been accessing the twitter api to pull a user_timeline for a list of users and the json that comes back is impossible to work with. I tried to deserialize it using javascriptserializer and get an error:

invalid object passed in , ':' or '}'

Now this is frustrating since I expect the json being returned to be error free. Then I tried json.net and split the posts using string.split and tried to convert each post to Jobject or jarray. for Jarray I get

'unexpected end of content while loading jArray

for jobject:

'error reading JObject from jsonreader. Current jsonreader item is not an object, StartArray'

This is really frustrating.

Here is a sample of the start of the json and the end:

```
[{"created_at":"Tue May 08 10:30:05 +0000   2012","id":199808381991653377,
  "id_str":"199808381991653377",
  "text":"@waddehawk Sorry for the misinformation earlier,
          this should be tomorrow after 2pm.",
  "source":"\u003cahref=\"http:\/\/www.awarenessnetworks.com\/home\/\"                              
  "truncated":false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id":199796940358156288,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str":"199796940358156288",
  "in_reply_to_user_id":333905755,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"333905755",
  "in_reply_to_screen_name":"waddehawk",
  "user":
  {"id":95310018,"id_str":"95310018",
  "name":"DBS Bank","screen_name":"dbsbank","location":"Singapore",
  "description":"The DBS official channel, 
  we're here Mon-Fri, 9am-6pm. Otherwise, call us 
  at 18001111111 or contact us via www.dbs.com\/contact",
  "url":"http:\/\/www.dbs.com","protected":false,
  "followers_count":1350,"friends_count":173,"listed_count":58,
  "created_at":"Tue Dec 08 00:07:04 +0000           2009","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":28800,
  "time_zone":"Singapore","geo_enabled":false,
  "verified":false,"statuses_count":306,"lang":"en",
  "contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,
  "profile_background_color":"CC0000",
  "coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,
  "retweet_count":1,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false}]
  {"created_at":"Tue May 08 19:45:51 +0000   2012","id":199948247710703616,
  "id_str":"199948247710703616",
 "text":"@mhess4 We agree! We still have several days to go. Hope you'll 
    be able to  make it to one of our stops before Fri!",
  "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.exacttarget.com
  \/products\/social.aspx?utm_source=sp1\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eSocialEngage\u003c\/a\u003e",
 "truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":199527746962071553,
 "in_reply_to_status_id_str":"199527746962071553",
 "in_reply_to_user_id":36889749,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"36889749",
 "in_reply_to_screen_name":"mhess4","user":
 {"id":80374332,"id_str":"80374332","name":"Citibank",
  "screen_name":"Citibank","location":"","description":"Special offers, 
  ideas for managing your financial life, and 
   other updates from  Citibank","url":"http:\/\/www.citi.com",
  "protected":false,
  "followers_count":9221,"friends_count":8454,
  "listed_count":245,"created_at":"Tue Oct 06 18:49:45 +0000 2009","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":-18000,
 "time_zone":"Quito","geo_enabled":false,"verified":true,
 "statuses_count":1592,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":true,
 "is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED",
 "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com
 \/profile_background_images\/95956292\/twitter_bg_1280x1024.jpg",
 "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com
 \/profile_background_images\/95956292\/twitter_bg_1280x1024.jpg",
 "profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com
  \/profile_images\/853331211\/citi-co-r-3d_sm_rgb_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":
"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/853331211\/citi-co-r-3d_sm_rgb_normal.jpg","profile_link_color":"0084B4",
 "profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",
 "profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,
 "show_all_inline_media":false,"default_profile":false,
 "default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,
 "notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,
 "contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false},..
```

Now I have formatted the code here and not pasted the whole file but it does look like valid json to me and I do not alter anything after receiving the stream from the twitter api. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I really need to get this stuff parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, figured it out. Was panicking too much and did not see obvious soln. I just ensured I clean up the json and validated it using an online http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
cleaner. Did this and was able to convert to JObject using json.net